# What is the appropriate data type for a course_code?

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay, I am asked to prepare a university database and I am required to store certain data in certain way.
For example, I need to store a course code that has a letter and followed by two integers. eg. I45,D61,etc.
So it should be VARCHAR(3) am I right? But I am still unsure whether this is the right path for it. I am also unsure how I am going to enforce this in the SQL script too. 
I can't seem to find any answer for it in my notes and I am currently writing the data dictionary for this question before I meddle into the script.

Any tips?

Comment: Depends: Do the letters mean anything? are the two integers forming an index of anything? are they ordinal? A possible alternative is using a column with VarChar(1) for the letter and a column with Int for the two integers. But only if this adds any value to your data. For example: imagine you ever want to get all courses of type D.

Comment: yes it can be varchar(3)

Comment: I what you're saying and I would just implement it that way. However, this course code must consist of one letter followed by two integers.

Comment: From an efficiency PoV, `VARCHAR(n)` takes up `n+1` bytes. If all course codes follow those rules exactly you may want to consider `CHAR` (`n` bytes) instead.

Comment: Cleanest choice is: make it a domain, based on CHAR(x) or varchar(x), or varchar(). If ever the need arises for a course named 'CS101', you'll only have to alter the constraints for the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As much as possible, make primary key with no business meaning. You can easily change your database design without dearly affecting the application layer side. With dumb primary key, the users don't associate meaning to the identifier of a certain record.

What you are inquiring about is termed as intelligent key, which most often is user-visible. The non user-visible keys is called dumb or surrogate key, sometimes this non user-visible key  become visible, but it's not a problem as most dumb key aren't interpreted by the user. An example, however you want to change the title of this question, the id of this question will remain the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412621/

With intelligent primary key, sometimes for aesthetic reasons, users want to dictate how the key should be formatted and look like. And this could get easily get updated often as often as users feel. And that will be a problem on application side, as this entails cascading the changes on related tables; and the database side too, as cascaded updating of keys on related tables is time-consuming

Read details here:

http://www.bcarter.com/intsurr1.htm

---

Advantages of surrogate keys: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

You can implement natural keys(aka intelligent key) alongside the surrogate key(aka dumb key)

```
-- Postgresql has text type, it's a character type that doesn't need length, 
-- it can be upto 1 GB
-- On Sql Server use varchar(max), this is upto 2 GB

create table course
(
    course_id serial primary key, -- surrogate key, aka dumb key

    course_code text unique, -- natural key. what's seen by users e.g. 'D61'

    course_name text unique, -- e.g. 'Database Structure'
    date_offered date
);
```

The advantage of that approach is when some point in the future the school expand, then they decided to offer an Spanish language-catered Database Structure, your database is insulated from the user-interpreted values that are introduced by the user.

Let's say your database started using intelligent key :

```
create table course
(
    course_code primary key, -- natural key. what's seen by users e.g. 'D61'

    course_name text unique, -- e.g. 'Database Structure'
    date_offered date
);
```

Then came the Spanish language-catered Database Structure course. If the user introduce their own rules to your system, they might be tempted to input this on course_code value:
**D61/ESP**, others will do it as **ESP-D61**, **ESP:D61**. Things could get out of control if the user decided their own rules on primary keys, then later they will tell you to query the data based on the arbitrary rules they created on the format of the primary key, e.g. "List me all the Spanish language courses we offer in this school", epic requirement isn't it? So what's a good developer will do to fit those changes to the database design? He/she will formalize the data structure, one will re-design the table to this:

```
create table course
(
    course_code text, -- primary key
    course_language text, -- primary key

    course_name text unique,
    date_offered date,

    constraint pk_course primary key(course_code, course_language)
);
```

Did you see the problem with that? That shall incur downtime, as you needed to propagate the changes to the foreign keys of the table(s) that depends on that course table. Which of course you also need first to adjust those dependent tables. See the trouble it could cause not only for the DBA, and also for the dev too.

If you started with dumb primary key from the get-go, even if the user introduce rules to the system without your knowing, this won't entail any massive data changes nor data schema changes to your database design. And this can buy you time to adjust your application accordingly. Whereas if you put intelligence in your primary key, user requirement such as above can make your primary key devolve naturally to composite primary key. And that is hard not only on database design re-structuring and massive updating of data, it will be also hard for you to quickly adapt your application to the new database design.

```
create table course
(
    course_id serial primary key,
    course_code text unique, -- natural key. what's seen by users e.g. 'D61'
    course_name text unique, -- e.g. 'Database Structure'
    date_offered date
);
```

So with surrogate key, even if users stash new rules or information to the course_code, you can safely introduce changes to your table without compelling you to **quickly** adapt your application to the new design. Your application can still continue and won't necessitate downtime. It can really buy you time to adjust your app accordingly, anytime. This would be the changes to the language-specific courses:

```
create table course
(
    course_id serial primary key,

    course_code text, -- natural key. what's seen by users e.g. 'D61'
    course_language text, -- natural key. what's seen by users e.g. 'SPANISH'

    course_name text unique, -- e.g. 'Database Structure in Spanish'
    date_offered date,

    constraint uk_course unique key(course_code, course_language)
);
```

As you can see, you can still perform a massive `UPDATE` statement to split the user-imposed rules on course_code to two fields which doesn't necessitate changes on the dependent tables. If you use intelligent composite primary key, restructuring your data will compel you to cascade the changes on composite primary keys to dependent tables' composite foreign keys. With dumb primary key, your application shall still  operate as usual, you can amend changes to your app based on the new design (e.g. new textbox, for course language) later on, any time. With dumb primary key, the dependent table doesn't need a composite foreign key to point to the course table, they can still use the same old dumb/surrogate primary key

And also with dumb primary key, the size of your primary key and foreign keys won't expand

Answer (score 2):

This is the domain solution. Still not perfect, check can be improved, etc.

```
set search_path='tmp';

DROP DOMAIN coursename CASCADE;
CREATE DOMAIN coursename AS varchar NOT NULL
    CHECK (length(value) > 0
    AND  SUBSTR(value,1) >= 'A' AND SUBSTR(value,1) <= 'Z'
    AND  SUBSTR(value,2) >= '0' AND SUBSTR(value,2) <= '9' )
    ;

DROP TABLE course CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE course
    ( cname coursename PRIMARY KEY
    , ztext varchar
    , UNIQUE (ztext)
    );
INSERT INTO course(cname,ztext) 
  VALUES ('A11', 'A 11' ), ('B12', 'B 12' ); -- Ok
INSERT INTO course(cname,ztext)
  VALUES ('3','Three' ), ('198', 'Butter' ); -- Will fail
```

BTW: For the "actual" PK, I would probably use a surrogate ID. But the domain above (with UNIQUE constraint) could serve as a "logical" candidate key.

That is basically the result of the *Table is Domain* paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you not get too specific about the datatype, so something like `VARCHAR(8)` would be fine. The reasons are:

- Next year there might be *four* characters in the code. Business needs change all the time, so don't lock down field lengths too much
- Let the application layer handle validation - after all, it has to communicate the validation problem to the user
- You're adding little or no business value by limiting it to 3 chars
- With mysql, although you can *define* `check` constraints on columns (in the hope of "validating" the values), they are ignored and are allowed for compatibility reasons only

Of all the components of your system, the database schema is always the hardest thing to change, so allow some flexibility in your data types to avoid changes as much as possible.